# PHP mail Function does not send my mail to my gmail

Tags: php, html, forms, email, gmail

I have managed to get the mail function to work kind of but even when I send the email it doesn't show up I did everything that these 2 youtube videos  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TmD4ly7V_E & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDPIJkkWqQU told me to do and that fixed most of the problems but know even when I submit a form from my website using xxamps local host and nothing pops up the email doesn't end up in my email and I can't figure out why is there any way you could help me?

I changed my php_ini settings following the instructions from the youtube videos and when I use my form and try to submit it to my gmail it just doesn't show up and this is for my penn fosters class so I'm not that advanced so please keep the solutions simple if you can.

Comment: For reference, we are not going to plow through even one YouTube video to see what the issue is.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The first question is of course, Do you have a Mail Server Installed and configured on your system and does you PHP.INI correctly point to that mail server

Comment: Mail can be complex for the noninitiated. There are so many factors involved. You could choose to not run your own mailserver, and instead use another. Even the GMail server can be used. Or choose a mail service API. There are lots of them.